# Bind Poptop (PPTPD) to a specific interface

Tags: pptpd, point-to-point-protocol

I have a poptop pptpd running on a server with 16 public IP's

I am getting clients to connect to (for example) eth1:8's IP (I also have pptpd set to listen on the address in /etc/pptpd.conf) the initial connection starts but the GRE packets start going out of eth1's IP, the upshot is firewalls dislike the traffic and block it.

Does anyone know how to get around this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an eth1:8 is an alias only, there is no traffic could be in an alias ;) 
so you just add permission for GRE to eth1